# Restricted Domain and Range

Tags: functions

If i have $f|_A(x)=\psi(x)$ where I have $f:X\to Y$, and $\psi:A\to Y$ and i set it so i have $f(x)=x$, and i set that $X=Y=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then for this i get that

$$f(x)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
and i get $$\psi(x)=\{1,2,3\}$$

which means that $\psi:A\to A$

even though $\psi:A\to Y$, we don't use some elements from it, does that matter? does is still maps to $Y$ or can i just say that it maps to range $A$?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You mean $f(X) = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $f(A)=\{1,2,3\}$
2. It does matter. $\psi \colon A \rightarrow A$ is surjective while the other version is not. In other words, the co-domain is part of the data of a function.

Comment: thank you, that is ok. for your point 1, you are saying that since i put a set(range) into $f$, i should get out a set(domain). whereas $f(x)=y$ i should only write element maps to element, e.g $f(1)=1$,$f(2)=2$,...,$f(5)=5$

Comment: @beginner Yeah, exactly. It was just a comment on notation.

Comment: @beginner No problem. You are 13?! I was eating glue at 13!

Comment: i am 11, but the site didn't let me put in may 12th 2003 because i need to be 13 too join i think